# click on a button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sidebar but I have a problem when using media queries. If the window is smaller than 991 i am not able to toggle the side menu again.

So I will remove the media queries and just toggle the menu button when the window is smaller than 991px otherwise show it again by clicking again on the button

So I will need something like this. **(this doesn't work because it will click the menu everytime i resize)**. How can I do this?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   var width = $(window).width();

   if(width < 991) {
       //to hide
       $('#sidebar-btn').click();
   }
   else {
       //to show
       $('#sidebar-btn').click();
   }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to toggle (show/hide) the sidebar on click?

Comment: Since both `if` and `else` contain the same code, there is essentially no check. Also, what you're trying to do seems like a `CSS` job to me.

Comment: use this : https://github.com/hidaytrahman/hr-accordion-tab

Answer (score 0):

You can just track whether it's hidden or not. However simulating a click for this is bizarre and not recommended practice.

You should have a media query for this in css, which hides or shows the sidebar depending on screen size. That would also be more efficient than a resize event hook.

```
var sidebarHidden = false;

$(window).resize(function () {
   var width = $(window).width();

   if(width < 991 && !sidebarHidden) {
       //to hide
       $('#sidebar-btn').click();
       sidebarHidden = true;
   }
   else if (width >= 991 && sidebarHidden) {
       //to show
       $('#sidebar-btn').click();
       sidebarHidden = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: i did media queries but if the width is small the media queries will trigger and I can never click on the menu again.

Comment: and your code doesn't work well. while i'm resizing it triggers the click many times.

Comment: I've adjusted it. Your media query should show the sidebar above a certain width and hide it below, so not being able to click on it again shouldn't be a problem?